# Using will and would to talk about future

Tags: sentence-construction

a) Ok sir, I will send you that file tomorrow. (Definitely)

b) Ok Sir, I would send you that file tomorrow. (Probably)

In above sentences can we use Will interchangeably and imagine the meaning given in bracket?

Sentence a) Indicate that I will definitely send him file.

Sentence b) Indicate that I would send him file if I found It.

I am aware that would is mainly use as past tense for will but my question is for future tense. 
Can we use Would to talk about future?

Answer (score 1):

No.  The word Would indicates a conditional case.  As such, it is referring to the present.  Example:

> "If it rained, I would bring my umbrella."

Please note that "rained" here refers to *present conditional* and not the past.  In this sentence, I don't mean to say that it has rained.  I mean to say in the off chance it *does* rain, I *would* bring my umbrella.

If I wanted to refer to a condition leading to a *future* action, it becomes far more simple.  I might say something like:

> "If it rains tomorrow, I will bring my umbrella."

In this case you would never use "would."   There are other ways of expressing doubt and chance (note the usage of "will" is still present here):

> "Maybe it will rain, and in that case, I will bring my umbrella."

Answer (score 0):

If you say

> I would send you that file tomorrow

without if clause, that is, without clearing in which conditions you would send it, it sounds like you can send the file but you will not. Therefore, you cannot use "would" instead of "will" in this sense.

if you say

> I would send him file if I found It

, that implies there is little possibility you can find the file. It has nothing to do with past tense.

Therefore, you should say

> I will send you if I find the file.

if there is a possibility that you can send the file. This possibility is stronger.

---

Would can be used to indicate future tense if you narrate a context  that is happened already in the past. For example,

> Arnold knew he would be tired the next day.